# How to Quickly Expand a Table Structure with Index?

Tags: tables, longtable, tabularray

I have created a table with 10 rows, but I would like to replicate the structure with an index for up to 30 or more rows. Is there an easy way to expand the table without having to manually add vertical and horizontal lines, as well as merge cells one by one?

[image]

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}


\begin{document}


\begin{longtblr}{
  width=\linewidth,
  cells = {c},
  cell{2}{1} = {r=3}{},
  cell{5}{1} = {r=3}{},
  cell{8}{1} = {r=3}{},
  vline{1-2} = {1-10}{},
  vline{5} = {1-10}{},
  hline{1-2,5,8,11} = {-}{},
  hline{3-4,6-7,9-10} = {2-4}{},
  colspec= {c *{3}{X[c,m]} },
  colsep=3pt,
  rowsep=3pt,
  row{1} = {font=\bfseries},
}
No & CT1      & CT2      & CT3  \\
1   & A        & B        & C \\
    &          &          &  \\
    &          &          &  \\
2   &          &          &     \\
    &          &          &     \\
    &          &          &     \\
3   &          &          &     \\
    &          &          &     \\
    &          &          &     
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```